# My jasmine test cases are failing in IE11

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, jasmine, local-storage

In my jasmine test cases in beforeEach block I used window.localStorage, which is working fine in chrome and in firefox. But in IE11 my testcases are failing.

Is there any alternative way for this to work in IE11 also?

I used it as below in beforeEach block: 
window.localStorage.removeItem("user");
window.localStorage.setItem("abc", "some data here");

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: window.localStorage value is coming as undefined in IE.

Comment: According to mdn, `localStorage` should be supported by IE8+. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Yeah in their documentation it is mentioned. But when I verify it in IE11 it did not work.